# Creating and printing a 2D array from a .dat file

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I need take data from a .dat file and put into an area for a "game of life" java program. Basically in this game, theres a 25x75 board that has cells in some of its coordinates. Theres this whole thing about some cells dying if they don't have neighbor and so I am trying to put the board in a [25+1][75+1] array so things are simpler for cells on the edge of the board.

I basically have two methods that put the data in the .dat file into an array and a method to print the array. However, when printed the array only has 24 rows for some reason. Basically everything seems just fine except its not printing the last line of the board. Any idea what went wrong with the code? Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Heres what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class GameOfLife {
    final public int M = 25;
    final public int N = 75;
    public char oldGen [][] = new char [M+1][N+1];
    public char newGen [][] = new char [M+1][N+1];

    public GameOfLife(){
        Scanner consoleReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        char [][] initialGen = new char [M+1][N+1];
        System.out.print ("Enter a filename: ");
        String filename = consoleReader.next();
        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner fileReader = null;
        try{ 
           fileReader = new Scanner (file);
        }catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.print("File " + file + " does not exist.");
           System.exit(0);
        }for (int i = 1; fileReader.hasNextLine() && i <= M; i++) {
            char [] chars = fileReader.nextLine().toCharArray();
            for(int j = 0; fileReader.hasNextLine() && j < N; j++){
                initialGen[i][j] = chars[j];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Initial Generation:");
        printGen(initialGen);
        this.oldGen = initialGen;
        consoleReader.close();
    }
    public void printGen(char gen[][]){
        for(int i = 1; i <= M; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < N; j++){
                System.out.print(gen[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: This looks wrong on first glance: `for(int j = 0; fileReader.hasNextLine()` why do you care about next line in the ***inner*** loop? The outer loop yes, since there you read the line and create rows, but the inner loop fills the row, and the line has already been read in.

Comment: Also your arrays should probably not have the M+1 and N+1 size but rather M and N sizes, and start your for loops at 0.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Damn getting rid of the .hasNextLine() fixed it for me. Thanks, didn't realize it was so simple. And also I'll try that out. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, this line: `fileReader.hasNextLine()` does not belong as a loop condition in the inner loop, since when that loop is called, the important line has already been extracted from the file, and this condition will prevent the last line of the file from being processed. I also suggest that you change your array lengths to M and N and not the `+ 1` versions, since your code is fighting against the Java library and how it is normally used and may confuse others who read your code, or your future self after you have learned and ingested Java standards.

As a side bit, note that Java 8 can allow you to read and split your file a bit more simply, letting the code figure out the array lengths for you. Something like this could work:

```
    String[][] array = null;
    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePathString))) {
        array = lines.map(s -> s.split(""))
                     .toArray(String[][]::new);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```